# Проверка расстановки запятых

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, сложное-предложение, деепричастный-оборот, определения

*Зима, повеяв холодом, внезапно отступила, и начались дожди, затяжные холодные.*
Проверьте, пожалуйста, предложение на правильность расстановки запятых.

Answer (score 1):

1. *Повеяв холодом* — деепричастный оборот; выделяется с двух сторон запятыми.
2. *Зима отступила, и начались дожди* — в предложении две основы; в этом случае перед союзом "и" ставится запятая.
3. *Дожди, затяжные, холодные* — определения (затяжные, холодные) стоят после определяемого слова (дожди), поэтому запятая ставится и после слова "дожди", и между определениями.

**Зима, повеяв холодом, внезапно отступила, и начались дожди, затяжные, холодные.**

[Обособление согласованных определений](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/714-233_obosoblenie_soglasovannyh_opredelenii.html)
[Трудные случаи пунктуации. Запятая перед союзом «И»](https://videotutor-rusyaz.ru/uchenikam/teoriya/315-zapyatayaperedsyuzomi.html)

P. S. После запятой всегда должен быть пробел.